# Symfony 2 - can't clear cache - You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request")

Tags: symfony

whenever I try to clear the cache on the console I get the following error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException]   
  You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Thanks.

**Edit: Sample of code:**

```
//accessing request object
namespace Greg\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use HvH\APIschemaBundle\Controller\Validation;
use HvH\APIschemaBundle\Controller\Helpers;

//FOSRestBundle
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function testAction(Request $request) 
    {                       
        //get any query strings
        $query_strings = $request->query->all();
        return($query_strings);
    }
}
```

**XML**
Not sure which file you are looking for...

Comment: Please, can you specify which version of Symfony2 are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm using 2.0.10

Comment: Please can you provide sample from the part of your project which uses  the Request object and the xml file which inject the Request to your service. There are some other projects which have had similar bug and maybe we can provide you an out of the box solution depending on your code.

Comment: I've updated my question, I'm not sure which xml file you are looking for? I haven't touched any XML's

Comment: I'm also getting this error with assetic:dump

Comment: This kind of random bugs is pretty annoying, and it doesn't really tell you where the bug is ^^

Comment: check if any service as a controller you are using

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For example to manually create scope "request" in CLI you may overload the **initializeContainer** kernel method in **AppKernel** class, simply by doing:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel {
    public function registerBundles() {
        // ...
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader) {
        // ...
    }

    protected function initializeContainer() {
        parent::initializeContainer();
        if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
            $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
            $this->getContainer()->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Also, if you are using it in a __construct() function, you can put the code there, so its only used in that function

Comment: I have got it working in my command. I only need to add these two lines (..enterScope.. and set request) in the begining of execute function

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this problem by removing the request object in the constructor. As the CLI is headless there is no 'request' object unless it's manually created.

Comment: Is there an equivalent when you are in CLI mode ? I mean a "CLI request" with arguments etc...

Comment: This answer helped my by removing the request from the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Try running this `rm -rf app/cache/*` ... This method is just the linux way of deleting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is what i've been doing. I guess there isn't really a downside to doing that but I don't like random bugs!

Comment: I'm also getting this error with assetic:dump so this isn't really a solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on [Шатов Максим](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737151/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC)'s answer I've created a request to site's root so that assetic twig asset filters (cssrewrite) would be able to resolve asset urls:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected function initializeContainer()
    {
        parent::initializeContainer();
        if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
            $request = new Request();
            $request->create('/');
            $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
            $this->getContainer()->set('request', $request, 'request');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem but I wasn't doing anything special with requests in my own services - it appeared the error was related to the request service itself within Symfony core.

I solved it by doing a `composer install` which didn't change vendors (already installed) but did run `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap` as a side-effect and that seemed to sort the problem.